# Using breakpointOnError() in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, combine

There are several methods within Combine like...

- `breakpointOnError()`
- `breakpoint(receiveSubscription:receiveOutput:receiveCompletion:)`

What happens if you forget to remove these and it goes into a release build? Does the compiler pass them over because there's a release flag on the build or do I risk an exception?

Comment: Why not just build a release build and find out?

Comment: @robmayoff because it takes 2 hours to run the Jenkins job

Comment: It would take 3 minutes to create a new project from scratch, type in four lines of code, and run it in release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIGTRAP, produced by `breakpointOnError`, crashes the process when not attached to a debugger. So the app will crash whenever the debugger is not attached - both in debug and production builds.

I have filed a feedback #FB9626473.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/breakpointonerror())

**breakpointOnError()**

> When the upstream publisher fails with an error, this publisher raises the SIGTRAP signal, which stops the process in the debugger. Otherwise, this publisher passes through values and completions as-is.

So yes, this stops the process in the debugger.

**Edit**

SIGTRAP stops the process in the debugger and will crash the app if the debugger is not attached, although this isn't the expected behaviour.

Comment: The default handling of `SIGTRAP` when not under a debugger is that it makes the process dump core. Have you checked that `breakpointOnError` only raises `SIGTRAP` when it detects that the process is running under a debugger?

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the app will crash with SIGTRAP when not attached.